# How to get the Start Date of the current Quarter populated in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am generating a report in SSRS, in which I got a start date field, which should populate the Start date of the current quarter automatically. Can someone please help me, how do I do this?. Thanks heaps

Answer (score 8):

T-SQL for current quarter:

```
SELECT DATEADD(qq,DATEDIFF(qq,0,GETDATE()),0) AS FirstDayOfCurrentQtr
```

Or SSRS expression if you want to set the value that way:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Quarter, DateDiff(DateInterval.Quarter, CDate("1/1/1900"), Today()), CDate("1/1/1900"))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to avoid having an additional dataset, you could use this expression as the default value for the parameter:

```
=DateSerial(Datetime.Today.Year,3 * ((datetime.Today.Month -1 )/3 + 1) -2, 1)
```

That's pretty ugly though.  More ideally create a function that you cacan call that from the expression:

```
Function getQuarter (byVal d As DateTime) As DateTime

Dim quarter as Integer = (d.Month -1) / 3 + 1
Dim quarterStart  AS new DateTime(d.Year, 3 * quarter - 2, 1)
getQuarter = quarterStart

End Function
```

Put the above in the code section of the report properties and in the expression call it by:

```
=Code.GetQuarter(Today)
```